# null percentage dynamic sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following sql:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Schema NVARCHAR(100) = 'dbo'
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =''

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Nulls') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #Nulls

CREATE TABLE #Nulls 
(
     TableName sysname, 
     ColumnName sysname, 
     ColumnPosition int, 
     NullCount int, 
     NonNullCount int
)

select @sql += 'select TableName = ''' + quotename(table_schema) + '.' + 
quotename(table_name) + ''' , ColumnName = ''' + quotename(column_name) 
+ ''' , ColumnPosition = ''' + convert(varchar(5) , ordinal_position) 
+ ''' , CountNulls = sum(case when ' + quotename(column_name) + ' is null  
then 1 else 0 end) , CountnonNulls = count(' + quotename(column_name) + ') 
from ' + quotename(table_schema) + '.' + quotename(table_name) + ';' + char(10)

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema AND (@Table IS NULL OR TABLE_NAME = @Table)

INSERT INTO #Nulls 
    EXEC sp_executesql @sql

SELECT * 
FROM #Nulls
```

However, I would like the database name in the first column, the schema name inn the second and not joined like it currently is and lastly at the end column showing total number of null as a percentage?

Thank you

Comment: No idea what the question is. To change the order of the select? You can do it yourself.

Comment: sorry, if you run that sql, it gives you null counts, however I want to add a columnd for database. Schema is already there but want it separated into its own column and finally put a column does does a percentage of total row counts

Comment: I still don't understand the percentage part, percentage of NULLs out of which column(s) ?

Comment: percentage of nulls for whatever database this runs on, so for example if this is running on adventureworks it will run for every tables and columns in that database and give the null for each column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want your code to gather data about tables in all databases on the server, you need to iterate over each database separately:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON

DECLARE @Schema NVARCHAR(100) = 'dbo'
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =''

IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Nulls') IS NOT NULL 
    DROP TABLE #Nulls

CREATE TABLE #Nulls 
(
        DbName sysname,
        SchemaName sysname,
        TableName sysname, 
        ColumnName sysname, 
        ColumnPosition int, 
        NullCount int, 
        NonNullCount int
)

;
DECLARE @db_name VARCHAR(50) -- database name
DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR
        SELECT name
        FROM msdb.sys.databases
        -- Iterate over all databases, except for these
        WHERE name NOT IN ('master','model','msdb','tempdb')

OPEN db_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN

        SET @sql = 'USE ' + QUOTENAME(@db_name)
        EXEC sp_executesql @sql

        select @sql += 'select DbName = ''' + quotename(@db_name)
        + ''',  SchemaName = ''' + quotename(table_schema)
        + ''',  TableName = ''' + quotename(table_schema) + '.' + quotename(table_name)
        + ''' , ColumnName = ''' + quotename(column_name) 
        + ''' , ColumnPosition = ''' + convert(varchar(5) , ordinal_position) 
        + ''' , CountNulls = sum(case when ' + quotename(column_name) + ' is null  
        then 1 else 0 end) , CountnonNulls = count(' + quotename(column_name) + ') 
        from ' + quotename(table_schema) + '.' + quotename(table_name) + ';' + char(10)

        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE (@Table IS NULL OR TABLE_NAME = @Table)

        INSERT INTO #Nulls 
            EXEC sp_executesql @sql

        FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @db_name
END


CLOSE db_cursor  
DEALLOCATE db_cursor


SELECT * 
FROM #Nulls
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SET NOCOUNT ON
DECLARE @Schema NVARCHAR(100) = 'dbo'
DECLARE @Table NVARCHAR(100) = NULL
DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) =''
IF OBJECT_ID ('tempdb..#Nulls') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #Nulls

CREATE TABLE #Nulls (DataBaseName sysname,SchemaName sysname,TableName sysname, ColumnName sysname, 
ColumnPosition     int 
, NullCount int , NonNullCount int)

--select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS

select @sql += 'select DBName = '''+ quotename(TABLE_CATALOG) 
+''',SchemaName = '''+ quotename(table_schema) +''',TableName = '''
+ quotename(table_name) + ''' , ColumnName = ''' + quotename(column_name) 
+ ''' , ColumnPosition = ''' + convert(varchar(5) , ordinal_position) 
+ ''' , CountNulls = sum(case when ' + quotename(column_name) + ' is null  
then 1 else 0 end) , CountnonNulls = count(' + quotename(column_name) + ') 
from ' + quotename(table_schema) + '.' + quotename(table_name) + ';' + char(10)

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @Schema AND (@Table IS NULL OR TABLE_NAME = @Table)

INSERT INTO #Nulls 
EXEC sp_executesql @sql

SELECT *,NullCntPercentage = (case when isnull(NullCount,0)=0 then 0 else cast((NullCount*100.0/(NullCount+NonNullCount)) as decimal(15,2)) end) 
,NonNullCntPercentage = (case when NonNullCount=0 then 0 else cast((NonNullCount*100.0/(NullCount+NonNullCount)) as decimal(15,2)) end)
FROM #Nulls order by TableName,ColumnPosition
```

Below is the output

```
DataBaseName    SchemaName  TableName   ColumnName  ColumnPosition  NullCount   NonNullCount    NullCntPercentage   NonNullCntPercentage
[MyDB]           [dbo]       [EmpDtl1]     [EmpId]      1              1             6            14.29                85.71
[MyDB]           [dbo]       [EmpDtl1]   [EmpName]      2              1             6            14.29                85.71
```

Comment: This is what I needed, one additional little thing, how would I modify it so I can give the Databases to look at as an In list, as I would like to look at numerous databases? Thank you